# How do I create histograms for all variables except one in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

`df.hist()` gives you histograms for all variables.
`df.hist(column='age')` gives you a histogram for just age.

What if I want histograms for all variables except one? Do I have to do them separately? And what's the difference between using `df.hist()` and the Matplotlib version anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the column that you want to exclude in a variable:
`exclude = ["age"]`

And the plot the histogram accordingly:
`df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(exclude)].hist(figsize=(15, 10));`

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.hist(column=["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5"])
```

Try using this.

Comment: oh thanks! I was using single quotation marks so that's probably why it didn't work.

Comment: Quotes are not the reason. However you can check if this works.